# Decimal to binary with visualisation in python

Tags: python, converters

I need to create function to convert decimal numbers to binary, and visualise that process in this way:

for example 15:

```
15|1
7 |1
3 |1
1 |1

number 15 in binary is 1111 (from bottom to up).
```

I keep trying to do that, but I don't even know, than my function is correct. I know that python has a "bin" built in function, but its not possible to use it for that visualisation (or am I wrong?).

My last code:

```
FinalList = []
dividedList = []

number = 29
while number != 1:
    divided = number%2
    number = int(number/2)
    FinalList.append(divided)
    dividedList.append(number)
    print(divided)

if number == 0:
    print(0)
    FinalList.append(divided)
    dividedList .append(0)
else:
    print(1)
    FinalList.append(1)
    dividedList.append(1)


print(FinalList)
print(dividedList)
```

Can someone help me with that?

my output for number 230:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

[115, 57, 28, 14, 7, 3, 1, 1]
```

and should be:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

[230,115, 57, 28, 14, 7, 3, 1]
```

Comment: what will be output for lets say 27

Comment: Where did **`listaWynikow`** and **`listaDzielenia`** come from?

Comment: What output do you get and what output do you expect?

Comment: post edited. Sorry for mistakes

Comment: I get `['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0']`
`[230, 102, 38, 6, 6, 6, 2, 0]` for 230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps!

Minor change to your code

```
FinalList = []
dividedList = []

number = 29

print(bin(number))

while number != 1:
    _new_number, divided =  divmod(number, 2)
    print("{}|{}".format(number, divided))
    number = _new_number
    FinalList.append(divided)
    dividedList.append(number)

if number == 0:
    print('0|0')
    FinalList.append(divided)
    dividedList .append(0)
else:
    print('1|1')
    FinalList.append(1)
    dividedList.append(1)


print(FinalList[::-1]) # should match with the `bin` result
print(dividedList)
```

Answer (score 1):

loop through the enumeration of the binary representation of a number, converting the remainder back to decimal

```
number = 230
str = "{:b}".format(number)
b = []
d = []
for i,x in enumerate(str):
  b.append(x)
  d.append(int(str[i:],2))
print b
print d
```

for number = 15

```
['1', '1', '1', '1']
[15, 7, 3, 1]
```

for number = 230

```
['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0']
[230, 102, 38, 6, 6, 6, 2, 0]
```